# The field MyField must be a number doesn't appear

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on a web application using .NET Core 2.2, there is an input in which I enter my product price . The problem is when I enter string"ABC" rather than a number, the validation error message is

> **"ABC" is not valid.**

I think Validation message should be:

> **The field ProductPrice must be a number.**

Both of above messages are default validation errors. none of them is customized. My problem is getting the first one rather the second one.

This is my model:

```
[Column("Price", TypeName = "money")]
[Display(Name = " Product Price ")]
[Required]
public decimal? ProductPrice { get; set; }
```

what I'm missing here??

Comment: This might help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2#custom-validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

I found what I was missing. I forgot to add

```
@section Scripts {
<partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

at the bottom of the View.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the Range data annotation.

```
[Range(0, decimal.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid number.")]
```

[Reference Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute?view=netcore-2.2)

Comment: doesn't change anything. still I get Abc is not valid.

Comment: But if I enter number bigger than MAXVALUE e.g 480, I get "Please enter a valid number." error.

Comment: Hrm, there's another data attribute. I believe called DataType. I'm not able to test at the moment, but you could try that as well.